# Implementation of average power function of noise (APFN)

Tags: python, r, statistics, time-series

I am trying to apply the average power function of noise (APFN) method to time series data, but I haven't found any public implementation. Does anyone know if it exists? Or how to implement it in R or Python.

The APFN  is a new approach to detecting multi-periodicities in time series.

The formula is as follows:

[image]

The DOI of the article is:10.4236/ajor.2011.14034